# How to force Close of opened stream when stream write previously failed (bug in opening stream twice)?

Tags: streams, socket

I opened a stream like:

```
str = OpenWrite[NotebookDirectory[] <> "myStream.tsv"];
```

and made an error when writing the first line (meant to be the tsv headers):

```
WriteLine[strPrime, "Sampling_size", "Slope_fitted_model"] 
// should have been:
WriteLine[strPrime, "Sampling_size\tSlope_fitted_model"]
```

I cannot close the stream now, nor overwrite it.

```
str 
// str is now :
$Failed

Close[str] 
// yield error: Close::stream: $Failed is not a string, SocketObject, InputStream[ ], or OutputStream[ ].
```

If I try overwrite :

```
str = OpenWrite[NotebookDirectory[] <> "myStream.tsv"]; 
// now yield error:
// OpenWrite::aofil: /myPath/myStream.tsv already open as /myPath/myStream.tsv.
```

I tried `Delete[str]`, or `str = Null` ... not working either.

Can I force an open stream to close down?

**EDITED**

After comment I went to check again my question to replicate the error.

I found that opening the stream **twice** is sufficient to produce it.

**How to replicate the error - is it a bug?**

1.

```
strt = OpenWrite[NotebookDirectory[] <> "myStreamt.tsv"];
```

2.
Now, run again the same line once it is already opened, you'll obtain this error:

```
OpenWrite::aofil:[..]/myStream.tsv already open as [..]/myStream.tsv. 
OpenWrite::noopen: Cannot open [..]/myStream.tsv.
```

3.

Try to close the stream:

```
Close[strt]
// Close::stream: $Failed is not a string, SocketObject, InputStream[ ], or OutputStream[ ].
```

And `strt` variable is now: `$Failed`

I tried to Remove the variable (instead of Delete[])

```
Remove[strt]
```

It seems to nullify variables (they turn to blue color).

But when you try to openwrite again the stream with same variable, same error:

4.

```
strt = OpenWrite[NotebookDirectory[] <> "myStreamt.tsv"];
// OpenWrite::aofil:[..]/myStream.tsv already open as [..]/myStream.tsv. 
// OpenWrite::noopen: Cannot open [..]/myStream.tsv.
```

Cannot using a new stream with a variable of previously corrupted one.
Maybe trace is still pointing somewhere, from the void space ... :)
Only way I found is to close the kernel.

Any solution to Clean out corrupted variables - close / reset broken streams ?

Comment: You claim to have opened a file on a stream `str`, but you wrote to a stream `strPrime`. I looks to me that you should be closing `strPrime`.

Comment: hi @m_goldberg that was a typo - I opened a second stream after was having error, and mistaken when I was copy pasting here.